# Barcode scanner with more than one field in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-forms

[image]

My barcode scanner plugin Typescript file

```
     scanBarCode() {
        this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
          this.scannedbarCode = barcodeData.text;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
      }

clearbar(){

  this.scannedbarCode= null;
}
```

My HTML side of barcode scanner

```
 <ion-item *ngIf='item.datatype == "barcode"'>
         <ion-label  floating><b>{{item.label}}</b></ion-label>
           <button  ion-button small item-right color="primary" (click)="scanBarCode()">Scan Barcode</button>
           <button  ion-button small item-right color="danger" (click)="clearbar()">Clear</button>   
           <ion-input type="text" value={{scannedbarCode}}></ion-input>       
       </ion-item>
```

If i scanned barcode one the same value comes on the second barcode value.Is there is any to avoid these using anything inside ionic expression.The barcode field is generated dynamically according to data type "barcode".

If two field comes with data type "barcode " it will generate two fields like above.The problem is the is if i scanned one field the value apply simultaneously to all other field

Comment: Dont think it has anything to do with the plugin. You need two different variables for the 2 fields instead of one `scannedbarCode`

Comment: the fields are dynamic .it may depend by user...may 2 fields sometimes 10 fields.So how i manage this dynamic situation.i mean how handle this variable

Comment: have an additional field in `item` object? or maintain a separate array

Comment: additional field in item object.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/D2mUHtkb

Comment: `item.scannedCode = barcodeData.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Suraj Rao comment, you will need to manage a scanned bar code value for each item. This is a suggestion of how you can go about doing it:

1. Your data structure for `this.main2` will need to include 2 new fields:

   - `id`: A unique id for each item
   - `scannedBarCode`: barcode value for each item
2. At your .html, when scanning or clearing barcode, you will need to pass the `item.id` as a parameter and use `item.scannedBarCode` as your input value
3. At your .ts, when scanning or clearing barcode, you will need to iterate and get the item based on the given `id`

---

this.main2:

```
this.main2 =[
   { id: "1", label: "Scan barcode one", datatype: "barcode", lookupname: "null", order: "11", scannedBarCode: null, validations: Array(1) },
   { id: "2", label: "Scan barcode two", datatype: "barcode", lookupname: "null", order: "10", scannedBarCode: null, validations: Array(1) },
];
```

.html

```
<ion-item *ngIf='item.datatype == "barcode"'>
  <ion-label floating>
    <b>{{item.label}}</b>
  </ion-label>
  <button ion-button small item-right color="primary" (click)="scanBarCode(item.id)">Scan Barcode</button>
  <button ion-button small item-right color="danger" (click)="clearbar(item.id)">Clear</button>
  <ion-input type="text" value={{item.scannedBarCode}}></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

.ts

```
scanBarCode(id) {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.main2.length; i++) {
            if (this.main2[i].id == id) {
                this.main2[i].scannedBarCode = barcodeData.text;
                break;
            }
        }
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    });
}

clearbar(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.main2.length; i++) {
        if (this.main2[i].id == id) {
            this.main2[i].scannedBarCode = null;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```